# Inline conditions in Lua (a == b ? "yes" : "no")?

Tags: lua, conditional-statements, ternary

Is there anyway to use inline conditions in Lua?

Such as:

```
print("blah: " .. (a == true ? "blah" : "nahblah"))
```

Comment: There is a nice article on [lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TernaryOperator) about ternary operator, together with problem explanation and several solutions.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Sure:

```
print("blah: " .. (a and "blah" or "nahblah"))
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. However I don't think this is strictly true -- I don't use LUA -- but I think it shares a "flaw" with this approach over a ternary operator in other languages. Imagine: `(cond and false-value or x)` That will result in the `x` in all cases.

Comment: wouldn't that also print the value of A as well?

Comment: @glowcoder No. "The conjunction operator (and) returns its first argument if this value is false or nil; otherwise, and returns its second argument. The disjunction operator (or) returns its first argument if this value is different from nil and false; otherwise, or returns its second argument. Both and and or use short-cut evaluation, that is, the second operand is evaluated only if necessary" -- from http://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html

Comment: @pst very cool. I'll be 100% honest and say the most Lua I've ever done consists of rummaging through some WoW addons. Thanks for the detailed explanation (even if it is just copy/paste) :)

Comment: @pst is correct that if the intent is that `a and false or true` is not going to give the same answer as `not a`. This idiom is usually used for cases where the desired value if `a` is true cannot be `false` or `nil`.

Comment: If you are using this form with variables, you probably assume that the second variable is non-false, which means you should write `a and assert(b) or c`.

Comment: @user166390 I completely agree with your point, but it's "Lua", not "LUA" - it's not an acronym, it's the Portuguese word for moon.

Answer (score 51):

If the `a and t or f` doesn't work for you, you can always just create a function:

```
function ternary ( cond , T , F )
    if cond then return T else return F end
end

print("blah: " .. ternary(a == true ,"blah" ,"nahblah"))
```

of course, then you have the draw back that T and F are always evaluated....
to get around that you need to provide functions to your ternary function, and that can get unwieldy:

```
function ternary ( cond , T , F , ...)
    if cond then return T(...) else return F(...) end
end

print("blah: " .. ternary(a == true ,function() return "blah" end ,function() return "nahblah" end))
```

Comment: I think this is the most useful for boolean variables

Comment: This answer is actually better than the top answer because it works for booleans as well.

Comment: I think a more common edge case that this solution accommodates is when `t` is `nil`.

Comment: great! best awnser! works great with any type... and ternary inside ternary...nice work man! thanks

Answer (score 20):

You can usually do:

```lua
condition and ifTrue or ifFalse
```

but this isn't necessarily the best way to do it. The major reason why is because if `ifTrue` is a falsy value (some of the time), `ifFalse` will evaluate even if `condition` is a truthy value. One way to do it simply without much extra work is:

```lua
(condition and {ifTrue} or {ifFalse})[1]
```

which has the advantage of not only being an expression *and* not being subject to the problem of `ifTrue` being falsy which means it can handle *all* cases, but also has the advantage of short-circuiting (not evaluating the other expression). No need for extra functions or messing with complex aspects of Lua.

Comment: Damn, I thought this was wrong, per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525817/inline-conditions-in-lua-a-b-yes-no#comment6277088_5525835 BUT i tested it in the demo https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo and indeed you have to check if the middle expression is falsy...

Answer (score 2):

*Although this question is fairly very old, I thought it would be fair to suggest another alternative that syntactically appears very similar to that of the ternary operator.*

Add this:

```lua
function register(...)
    local args = {...}
    for i = 1, select('#', ...) do
        debug.setmetatable(args[i], {
            __call = function(condition, valueOnTrue, valueOnFalse)
                if condition then
                    return valueOnTrue
                else
                    return valueOnFalse
                end
            end
        })
    end
end

-- Register the required types (nil, boolean, number, string)
register(nil, true, 0, '')
```

And then use it like this:

```lua
print((true)  (false, true)) -- Prints 'false'
print((false) (false, true)) -- Prints 'true'
print((nil)   (true, false)) -- Prints 'false'
print((0)     (true, false)) -- Prints 'true'
print(('')    (true, false)) -- Prints 'true'
```

---

> ***Note:*** For tables, however, you cannot use them directly with the above method. This is because each and every table has it's own independent metatable and Lua does not allow you to modify all tables at once.
>
> In our case, an easy solution would be to convert the table into a boolean using the `not not` trick:
>
> ```lua
> print((not not {}) (true, false)) -- Prints 'true'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You could just write the if statement in one line, it is no shorthand, inline or ternary operator stuff tho.

```
if (dummy) then
    print("dummy is true")
end
```

is equal too

```
if (dummy) then print("dummy is true") end
```

Answer (score 1):

Lua is deliberately lightweight so it does not have a ternary operator.

There are a couple of ways to get past this including using the and-or idiom. But I think that is bad for multiple reasons. Mainly because beginners don't understand it though.

I suggest using a function:

```lua
local function choice(c, t, f)
    return c and t or f
end

local s = choice(2 % 2 == 0, "even", "odd")
```

Comment: This has the same flaw as the and-or idiom -- if the `t` is falsy it returns `f` even when `c` is truthy

Comment: You are 100% right. I said it was bad for *multiple* reasons. The main one being that it was confusing for beginners. There is a much better function that can be written but the point was that as the ternary operator does not exist people use "tricks" which are not obvious to the beginner. You can wrap it in a function that conveys the meaning better. Ideally, you would write tests to document what the function does and as you have pointed out this would soon reveal the underlying problem with the and-or idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Have fun
:D

```lua
local n = 12
do
    local x = (n>15)
            and print(">15")
            or n>13
            and print(">13")
            or n>5
            and print(">5")
end
```